# SQL Server Agent Jobs Priorities

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-agent

I am busy configuring my first SQL Backup policy and have run into a snag.

I want to use SQL Server Agent to run automated backup jobs, one for full weekly backups, one for daily differential backups and one for hourly transactional log backups.

My problem is, what will happen when all three jobs are due to run at the same time (say at midnight at the end of the week)? Obviously I want the transactional backup to run first, then a differential and then finally a full, reason being that the weekly full creates a new differential base.

This may be a completely wrong way to go about it, so I'm open to alternative suggestions or solutions.

Answer (score 0):

First, your question just partially concerned with SQL Server Agent Jobs. Jobs ans Job schedules are just a way to execute the maintenance commands (I mean BACKUP commands).

You can see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189315%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) the operations that can be executed concurrently; As you can see,
you cannot execute Full and Different backups at same time. But you can make full backup and log backup at same time, and differential backup and log backup at same time.

It is hard to recommend something about backup and recovery strategies without knowledge about your business needs, database size and growing, hardware, storage  and LAN configurations, but the concepts and examples for creating your backup and recovery you can found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187048%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175510%28v=sql.110%29.aspx).